# A Terrible Riddle

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> I know exactly what you fear,
>
> I use it to take away your cheer.
>
> Even though I appear to most,
>
> Some I can not even come close.
>
> You could say that I am a dark horse,
>
> Taking your hours with no remorse.
>
> You may think that I am stronger than any fist,
>
> But it is only through you that I exist.

Comment: My first though when I saw the title was "Lord Voldemort"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

<sub>This has some potential to be *too broad*.</sub>

Here's my thoughts on the answer:

> You are a **nightmare**

```
I know exactly what you fear,
I use it to take away your cheer.
```

> You come from our own psyches, and can use our own fears to bring us down.

```
Even though I appear to most,
Some I can not even come close.
```

> Most people have nightmares from time to time.
>  Some people never do.

```
You could say that I am a dark horse,
```

> Dark → night;  horse → mare

```
Taking your hours with no remorse.
```

> Robbing us of our sleep

```
You may think that I am stronger than any fist,
But it is only through you that I exist.
```

> You are the product of our own minds.

Comment: correct! it was my first riddle, i tried to make it specific enough. mostly the "dark horse" line i think narrows it down.

Comment: @thecoder16 I think the "dark horse" is the most nebulous line.

Comment: @AmagicalFishy if i'm interpreting you correctly, that means it is the most unclear. i thought that made it the most clear?

Comment: @thecoder16 I don't think so—I think you could remove that line and the one after it and the riddle would be just as clear (is there anyone else who could chime in?)

Comment: @AmagicalFishy I liked the dark horse line, I originally just thought 'sleep' or 'dreams' but after reading Rubio's answer, that was the one line that really separated out that the answer was 'nightmare'

Comment: @AmagicalFishy The dark horse line is the one that brought me specifically to the answer I gave, as opposed to depression or similar.  I think that line is key.

Comment: my moment of genius with wordplay xD

Comment: @AmagicalFishy You've obviously never heard of Nightmare Moon.

Comment: @jpmc26 I thought you were talking about the moon in Zelda. I looked it up on Google images and found... a cartoon horse? I've never heard of it, haha.

Comment: @AmagicalFishy Precisely. Said cartoon horse is also female. Night**mare** Moon. ;) It's quite a few years old now.

Comment: @thecoder16 You can accept an answer as correct by clicking the checkmark under Rubio's answer's vote count.

Comment: @OldBunny2800 yes, i know, i just always wait the standard 12-24 hours before accepting :)

Answer (score 0):

I would have guessed death. It's a nightmare to most, anyway.
I also would have guessed life. It's a nightmare to most, anyway.

Have you ever had a daymare?

Instead, knowing that dreams aren't real and assuming then that waking life must be real, I remembered that life is just a dream, and since dreams aren't real, after re-concluding that life also isn't real, finding a contradiction, re-concluding dreams, like waking life is both real and unreal, I'd (with respect of dues) have to go with consciousness.

I frequently awake with a jolt requiring a reality adjustment to the conscious mind, but I can't recall ever, EVER starting a dream like that.

Then again, everyone thinks I'm crazy.

With all that said, what makes it a terrible riddle? Terrible answers like this one? There are no terrible riddles, just terrible people. (No one laughs at my jokes either! ;) )

Comment: i named it a terrible riddle referencing nightmares, which most people will call terrible. :)

Comment: When is a terrible riddle not a terrible riddle? When it's terrible foreshadowing!  :)  Just kidding, of course, it's terribly clever! :P